# Using a Flag parameter to populate SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have a report that must be populated with data based on a `@Flag` parameter. The report is pulling from one stored procedure which calls data from 2 separate tables. For instance, `EQ.Equipment`, `EQ.Address`, `EQ.City`, `EQ.State`,... and `FL.Equipment`, `FL.Address`, `FL.City`, `FL.State`,...

I have added a Flag parameter that if `@Flag = 'E'` it will pull from the EQ `SELECT` statement and if `@Flag = 'F'` it will pull from the FL `SELECT` statement. Is this possible? If so, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (using the actual name of the tables):

```
IF (@PARAM = 'E')
BEGIN 
  select * from EQ_table
END
ELSE
  select * from FL_table
```

In the dataset properties map `@PARAM` to the parameter created in your report.

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: This does work. Thanks! Any idea how to use that as a hidden parameter?

Comment: If you hide it your user can't select the values 'E' or 'F' for the parameter.  Exactly, What do you mean?

Comment: The requirement is to have a hidden parameter where if an equipment number is entered then it will select 'E' and if a functional location number is entered then it will select 'F'. I am confused by this myself so I wanted to see if it was even possible. Would that be handled in my stored procedure somehow?

Comment: I think you have another parameter that is NOT hidden where you can enter equipment number, so you want your user enter the equipment and based on that number the hidden flag parameter be populated with the right value that lets choose which `select` statement will be executed. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is correct. I have an Entity parameter (Equipment or Functional Location) that is visible to the user. Can I tie the hidden parameter to that? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you map Enitity parameter directly to the query? I think In that scenario it is not necessary use a hidden parameter between the query and the visible parameter. Which values will the user enter in the Entity parameter? A code? a letter? How do you figure out the Location based on user input/selection?

Comment: Entity parameter is already mapped to the query. I will have to get some more clarity on what they need because I think there is some disconnect as to how this would work. I really appreciate all your feedback. You have been extremely helpful.